# Vertical padding %

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my home page divided into two areas one above (white) and the other below (black).

The page is intended to be divided vertically at 50% and it works fine.

Both area have a title, the white area on top (should have the title on the bottom side of it) while the dark area below should have the title on it's upper side. In this way the two titles are in the center of the page.

My only problem is that I cant find a way to bring down the title of the upper area.
The fastest way was to use padding-top and a %, but this way the padding would result a % of the width of the page and not its height.

Do you have any idea how to solve that?

HTML

```
<div>

<div style="height:50%; width:100%; background-color:#FFFFFF">
<a href="http://www.lorenzomeschini.com/architecture"; onMouseOver="this.style.color='#FCB415'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#cccccc'" style="text-align:center; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#dddddd; font-size:19px; letter-spacing:0.22em; height:100%">architecture</a>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; bottom:0;width:100%;height:50%">
<a href="http://www.lorenzomeschini.com/photography"; onMouseOver="this.style.color='#FCB415'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#cccccc'" style="text-align:center; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#cccccc; font-size:19px; letter-spacing:0.21em; height:100%">photography</a>
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
background-color: #1E1E1E;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #919191;
font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size: 13px;
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried `position: absolute` & `bottom: 0`?

Comment: as a last resort, you could make your titles into images adn position them as background images... background:white url(title1.png) no-repeat center bottom;

Comment: @Sven . yes I did tried, but the problem are not really the colors in the backgroung but the top title "architecture", which should be in the lower part of the white area. Thats where I'm stuck right now...

Answer (score 0):

You need to `position: absolute` the divs and place one on the top and one at the bottom, then it should work. Like so:

```
.white-div {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.black-div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4qhQg/

Note: when dealing with percentage heights, it may also be wise to make sure the body always spans 100% of the html height (although it seems to be working without this as well):

```
html {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative
}
body {
    height:100%
}
```

Comment: This works but not for the title "architecture", it should be on the lower part of the white area. Thats my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent divs of the 'a' tags

```
position:relative;
```

and the 'a' tags themsleves

```
position:absolute;
```

The firat 'a' should be

```
bottom: 0;
```

and the second

```
top:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first title down

Html (add

)

```
  <div class="white-div"> <p><a href="http://www.lorenzomeschini.com/architecture" ; onMouseOver="this.style.color='#FCB415'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#cccccc'" style="text-align:center; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#dddddd; font-size:19px; letter-spacing:0.22em; height:100%">architecture</a></p>

    </div>
```

css

```
.white-div p {
  text-align:center;
  width:500px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right : 50% ;
  margin-right:-250px;

}

p{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/okzpE)